# Java method reference to a method with generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, java-8, method-reference

I'm trying to make a method reference to a method which have a generic parameter specified in a class declaration. 
So I have:

```
public interface IExecutable<P extends IParameter> {

    void execute(P parameter);

}

public class Parameter implements IParameter {

    public void childSpecific() {
    ...
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    ...
    //somewhere in the code
    public void foo(Parameter parameter) {
        parameter.childSpecific();
    }

    public void test() {
        IExecutable<?> executable = this::foo; //compilation error
        // The type TestClass does not define inner(IParameter) that is applicable here
        executable.execute(new Parameter()); //compilation error as well
        // The method execute(capture#4-of ?) in the type IExecutable<capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Parameter)
    }
    ...
}
```

It's specific that I don't know the concrete generic type of the executable here. Using

```
IExecutable<Parameter> = ...
```

solves the problem immediately, but it's impossible for the case.

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong. But how to make it work?

Thx.

Comment: Does `IExecutable<IParameter>` work? Also, I think you are getting lots of warnings about missing generic types. Try to fix those.

Comment: If you have a reference of type `IExecutable<?>`, you wouldn't be able to invoke `execute` with anything other than the `null` literal as an argument. I therefore don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is an important difference between java7 and java8. In java7 this would work. In Java8 this evidently not.

Comment: @CommuSoft - I don't think java7 understands `this::foo` :)

Comment: @bayou.io: evidently not, but for equivalent cases it works different as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, foo is not written to handle any `IParameter` other than `Parameter`. You could assign a reference to foo to a variable of type `IExecutable<? extends IParameter>`, however this means that it is an executable that handles some unknown type of `IParameter` (in this case, `Parameter`). Since the specific subtype is unknown, it would not be syntactically safe to pass any subtype of `IParameter` in to its execute method, since you don't know which it can handle within this scope!

What you need is another type variable instead of using a capture (the ?). This way you can specify that the `IParameter` you're passing in is the same type as the `IParameter` the executable accepts. You could introduce this with a new method, like I'm doing below:

```
public class TestClass {
  public static void foo(Parameter parameter) {
    parameter.childSpecific();
  }

  public static void main(String args) {
    execute(TestClass::foo, new Parameter());
  }

  public static <P extends IParameter> void execute(
        IExecutable<P> executable, P param) {
    executable.execute(param);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I need (with the addition that methods and method references weren't statc).

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter `P` in your interface `IExecutable` is constrained to being a subtype of `IParameter`. Consider these two subtypes:

```
class Parameter implements IParameter { ... }
class AnotherParameter implements IParameter { ... }
```

Now, an `IExecutable<?>` is not more specific regarding the above mentioned constraint. In fact, the `?` states that it is bound to an *unknown* subtype of `IParameter`, which could be `Parameter` or `AnotherParameter` (in my example).

With such a variable declaration, you face the two problems you mentioned.

1. Your method `foo(Parameter)` does not match the more general constraint of an `IExecutable<?>`. As seen above, such an executable could be bound to `AnotherParameter` which clearly would violate the method signature of `foo`.
2. Even if it matched, it cannot be used like you did. The compiler does not know to which type the `?` actually was mapped. The only thing it knows: It must be a subtype of `IParameter`, but which one is not known. That means, the statement `executable.execute(new Parameter())` is not allowed (as also `executable.execute(new AnotherParameter())`). The only parameter you are allowed to pass to `execute` is `null`.

Conclusion: Point 1 could be solved by declaring the variable `executable` with type `IExecutable<? extends Parameter>`. This matches the method signature of `foo`. But point 2 still does not allow the call to `execute`.

The only thing you can do is to declare the variable as

```
IExecutable<Parameter> executable = this::foo;
```

This will compile and allow the call to

```
executable.execute(new Parameter());
```

Answer (score 0):

This line exposes failure in java type inference

```
IExecutable<?> executable = this::foo;
```

Let's look at it this way

```
IExecutable<?> executable = p->this.foo(p);
```

To compile it, java needs to know the meaning of `foo(p)`. Before java8, the type of an expression is built on the types of sub-expressions; here, the type of `p` needs to be known 1st to resolve `foo`. But the type of `p` is not specified, it needs to be inferred from surrounding context. Here the context is `IExecutable<? extends IParameter>`, and `p` is inferred to `IParameter` - and method `foo(Iparameter)` does not exist.

In general, type inference faces a dilemma, does it infer from top down, or bottom up? Java8 defines an extremely complicated procedure for that, which is humanly impossible to understand:)

Workarounds: specify the type of `p`

```
IExecutable<?> executable = (Parameter p)->this.foo(p);
```

or specify a more specific target type

```
IExecutable<?> executable = (IExecutable<Parameter>)p->this.foo(p);

IExecutable<?> executable = (IExecutable<Parameter>)this::foo;
```

If you ask the language designers, they'd consider all of this is quite obvious ... but a programmer's best action is probably just try different things till it works, than to study the actual language spec.

Comment: Even with the various casts, it is not possible to do `executable.execute(new Parameter())` with a `IExecutable<?> executable`.